# Erro ao abrir Package Manage Console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Quando abro o `Package Manage Console` me dá o a seguinte mensagem:

> Join-Path : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ChildPath'. Specified method is not supported.
>   At C:\Users\renan.carlos\Source\Repos\CodingCraft\ExerciciosCodingCraft\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:13 char:57
>   + ... rPackageDirectory = Join-Path $packageDirectory $compilerPackage.Name
>   +                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>
> Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
>   At C:\Users\renan.carlos\Source\Repos\CodingCraft\ExerciciosCodingCraft\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:14 char:44
>   + ... erPackageToolsDirectory = Join-Path $compilerPackageDirectory 'tools'
>   +                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Quero saber o que significa isso e se chega ser um erro? e como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Execute este comando para fazer atualização do package:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Comment: testei aqui, mas não funcionou